# C# REST message handler not handling when too many messages come in

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a C# .net core REST handler class that is as follows,

```
namespace ServerApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("Buckets")]
    public class MainMessageController : ControllerBase
    {
        private MessageProcessor messageProcessor;

        public MainMessageController(MessageProcessor messageProcessorInject)
        {
            messageProcessor = messageProcessorInject;
        }

        [HttpPost]        
        public async Task<IActionResult> MainMessage()
        {
            string body = string.Empty;

            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
            {
                body = await stream.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            
            ProcessingResponse rep = await messageProcessor.HandleMe(body);            

            if (rep.ResponseCode == 200)
                return Ok(rep);

            return BadRequest(rep);
        }
    }
}
```

The `MessageProcessor`  class takes care of processing the received message in the `HandleMe` method. This works perfectly and I have no issues. Yes, this is slightly(very slightly intensive, it processes the message and sends out the result to a kafka pipe - but as you see here it is done )

The problem is when I use a Python script to send messages in bulk, a lot of messages are missed. For example, I tried sending 155 messages through the script, but only 36 of them were processed. But if I introduce a small delay in the python script, it processes all 155 of them.

What should I do? What is the problem here? Isn't this something that should be already taken care of internally? Or should I do something to scale this handler? Also, the order in which the messages arrive matters, so I would like to maintain it.

**Update 1:**

The part of the python script that sends the messages is like this,

```
 with open('c:\\script_test\\script.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            if len(line.split()) == 0:
                continue
            else:
                req = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/Buckets", data=line)
                count=count+1
                if req.status_code != 200:
                    print("failure - "+req.status_code)
```

I dont get any errors and in the end and the count at the end is 155.

This is the kafka posting code in my c# program,

```
public void PostToKafka(List<RecordStructure> records, string topic, Action<DeliveryReport<Null,string>> deliveryMsgHandler)
{           

    string payload = string.Join(",", records.Select(m => "{ \"message\" : " + m.msg + "}"));
    string sendRecords = "{ \"record\": [" + payload + "]}";

    producer.Produce(topic, new Message<Null, string> { Value = sendRecords }, deliveryMsgHandler);
}
```

The `producer` is as defined follows,
`private readonly IProducer<Null,string> producer;`

Comment: Nothing we can say about this. This code doesn't look broken. Perhaps your kafka pipe misses messages (what does that code look like?) or your python script ignores errors returned from your controller.

Comment: Id be looking to python or your bus, if the request was dropping you should know about it up stream,

Comment: If you're running your REST service under IIS, I would suggest looking in the service log file...

Comment: how do you count processed requests? maybe there is a problem in kafka consumer